# How to dynamically add a drawable (.xml) to buttons (generated dynamically)

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have a method that creates dynamically an array of `Button`

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     Button button = new Button(activity);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 100);
     button.setLayoutParams(lparams);
     button.setTag(0);
     buttonArray[i] = button;
     layout.addView(button);
 }
```

I created a `drawable` (**d.xml**) that I have to apply to the buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

What I'm not able to do is to apply **d.xml** to the buttons that I create dynamically.

Can somebody help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set background resource of Button :

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     Button button = new Button(activity);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 100);
     button.setLayoutParams(lparams);
     button.setTag(0);
     button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.d);
     buttonArray[i] = button;
     layout.addView(button);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_resource);
```

Answer (score 1):

in your for loop, after `button.setTag(0);` do this `button.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.d));`

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created your background drawable, you can apply this to the dynamically generated Button in your code.

If your minimum build is API 21 (Lollipop), then use

```
button.setBackground(activity.getDrawable(R.drawable.d)
```

You can also use `setBackgroundDrawable` for lower APIs.

A more suitable solution can be to use

```
button.setBackgroundResouce(R.drawable.d)
```

Give those a go!